# Python vars nested assignment

Tags: python, variable-assignment, variables

An example of what the title talks about:

```
#seen in a demo of PyOpenGL
# http://PyOpenGL.sourceforge.net/
size = self.size = self.GetClientSize()
```

What is this used for? How does it works and when using it?

My idea is this allows to assign the value of the third item to the first and the second... If that's it, we can nest an infinite number of vars.

Comment: The language specification covers it here, if you want to read it yourself.  http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 8):

It is a chained assignment. You set both `size` and `self.size` to the return value of `self.GetClientSize()`.

You can chain assignments with abandon:

```
>>> foo = bar = spam = eggs = 'frobnicators'
>>> foo
'frobnicators'
>>> bar, spam, eggs
('frobnicators', 'frobnicators', 'frobnicators')
```

Note that the expression on the right-hand side only is evaluated once, and it's value is assigned to all the left-hand side variables from left to right.

This can most easily be seen if you decompiled the python bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     bar = baz = eggs = 'spam'
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('spam')
              3 DUP_TOP             
              4 STORE_FAST               0 (bar)
              7 DUP_TOP             
              8 STORE_FAST               1 (baz)
             11 STORE_FAST               2 (eggs)
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             17 RETURN_VALUE
```

`DUP_TOP` creates an extra reference to the value on the stack (`spam`), which is stored in `bar`, then `baz` is given another duplicated reference, then the value is stored in `eggs`.

Comment: Looks pretty neat now, using dis to explain it is a good idea.

Comment: Surprisingly, the assignment proceeds left to right, not right to left.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to assign the value on RHS to two variables in the same statement..

```
a = b = 2
```

Both a and b contains 2..

This can be used when you want to create an `alias` for your variable, you just assigned value to, because may be you want to use that value in two different ways..

Answer (score 0):

It is roughly equivalent to

```
temp=self.GetClientSize()
size=temp
self.size=temp
del temp
```

But it executes faster and is generally easier to read than this form.  Note that it is not the same as

```
self.size=self.GetClientSize()
size=self.getClientSize()
```

which executes self.getClientSize() 2 times, nor the same as

```
self.size=self.GetClientSize()
size=self.size
```

observe

```
class test(object):
    def setter(self, val):
        self._t=val
    def getter(self):
        return 5
    t=property(fget=getter,fset=setter)

a=test()
b=a.t=9
print a.t, b
```

prints 5 9