# What is difference between a=b=c and assign separately in programmatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Is there any difference between:

`a=b=c`

and

```
b = c
a = c
```

in python?
Will the interpreter read those things differently?

And what is the side effect when i use first/second method, if it has side effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your future googling, this is known as a "chained assignment" or "nested assignment". As shown by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12655914/1277637) chained assignments are useful for forcing the interpreter to only evaluate the right hand expression once. For example:

```py
a = b = myComputeHeavyFunc()  # Only one evaluation
```

will only evaluate `myComputeHeavyFunc()` once where as the multi-line solution evaluates the function twice, providing a performance loss:

```py
a = myComputeHeavyFunc()  # One evaluation
b = myComputeHeavyFunc()  # Another evaluation
```

Comment: @DevFallingstar no worries, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

If `c` is an existing object then both pieces of code will have the same effect, binding both `a` and `b` to the same existing object.

If `c` is a literal then the first will bind them to the same object whereas the second will create two separate objects (for a certain value of "create"; the difference only matters for mutable objects) and bind them to each name.